# Running child c executable as child process in node.js heroku app

Tags: node.js, heroku, buildpack

I want to run c program as child process in node.js on heroku.
In my app.js:

```
app.get('/extra', function (req, res) {
    const child = spawn('./a');
    child.stdin.setDefaultEncoding('utf-8');
    child.stdin.write(52 + "\n");
    child.stdin.end();

    child.stdout.on('data', (data) =>{
        const dataString = "" + data;
        res.send(dataString);
    });
});
```

I am using heroku c-buildpack with Makefile:
all:
gcc main.c -o a.out
It logs successful, but when I get /extra app fails, and when I tried to list all files with `fs.readdirSync('/').forEach...` it only logged app.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

switching

```
spawn('./a')
```

to

```
spawn('./a.out')
```

fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
const { child } = require("child_process")

child("ls", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(`[Error] ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
        console.log(`[Std Error] ${stderr}`);
        return;
    }
    console.log(`${stdout}`);
});
```

Can you try this, just running a system command `ls`.

Comment: used different syntax, but it worked, it listed a.out which must have been compiled by heroku, switched spawn('./a') to spawn('./a.out') fixed it. So it was syntax all along... xd

Comment: Owh, that always happens to me too, btw you can mark your answer as answered.